# magento installation on localhost giving creating admin account error

Tags: email, login

i have installed magento on local host successfully but one small problem m facing is when m trying to create admin account it is showing message "Only registered domain accounts are allowed" when m entering my email address.
can any person help me ?

Even we are facing this problem with actual site also when customer buy some product from our site and come back to buy another products magento shows the same message even when person click on forgot password it shows same message again.

Comment: I found no trace of this message in a magento instance. Are you sure you don't have any custom modules installed?

Comment: Phoenix_Moneybookers, QS_Googletranslate, Manv_Ajaxcoupon, Fable_Coupon these are custom modules which are currently activated and Ebizmarts_MageMonkey, Ebizmarts_Mandrill are modules which are disabled currently.

Comment: Why it is showing only registered domains are allowed which creating an account on localhost?

Comment: You either have a custom module installed or your are working off a modified core, or you have a local override. By default Magento does not contain registration restrictions. check your app/code/local/mage to see if you have any local overrides.

Comment: @eirik i can buy your point for a second but why i m facing this problem while installing it on localhost it is not allowing me to even create account on localhost. Showing "Only registered domain accounts are allowed" error while creating new account or using any earlier created account....

Comment: If you are trying to migrate/install a package that was previously modified this might be why. If you are using a fresh copy of magento downloaded from the website this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I have taken backup of website from hosting, added backup in XAMPP by creating folder named innova. Created database named head and changed details of database in local.xml then opened on browser localhost/innova and it is now showing installation...but showing error while adding base url...

Answer (score -2):

Only allow people who own an email with the business domain name to register [here](http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-restrict-user-registration-by-email-domain)

Comment: Please don't write single link answers. Even if it might be a good answer, you should explain in a few words what is found at the end of that URL.

Comment: @prasad i think this is not helpful because this is to change message only here i m not able to create account in my website and if created then not able to use it.

Comment: @prasad maganti, please explain your answer with more information. Even your answer is good that might not be enough with single line answer.